Input some PublicKey, PEM_read_bio_PUBKEY return null, Is the PublicKey wrong?
I use OpenSSL library to encrypt or decrypt the message for SMIME，now I have two PublicKey strings, and convert it to EVP_PKEY, the code is
EVP_PKEY* createPublicKey(const char* publicKeyString) {
    BIO* bio = BIO_new_mem_buf((void*)publicKeyString, -1);
    EVP_PKEY* pkey = PEM_read_bio_PUBKEY(bio, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    BIO_free(bio);
    return pkey;
}

But, when I use the PublicKey below, PEM_read_bio_PUBKEY return null
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGJAoGBAKvXgzoezmG2CrUt9jptn09LKscdS9vyTe1jP3vHfylbU93/+GVIhjlw
d7mM0ulSsi+O53+HElDQjY2ufqePRKGJ3NGzisF0YopEvU36xq0L2IG7g7gny08n
7f3HXg6TC0FcwOJRBVDhVXUwl3RiH06jGFp+iq2Ok3vngLrrFeg/AgMBAAE=
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----

and another PublicKey is ok
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAoMeN556vV68LEAQ1KE22
n6fHTCsVV1CwKMo8L6WvCMD13xNs72MwA+FNNOZUTg2+2HvaH7ZnwNgLPeY/O+Rc
vTBLI90qGxAubGYnvp+76hNROzXQfLFlTQdGiu2vF0oiCU00EDKM4xzL8iOf7H8A
aw9f6S0Y9UiaZAMJ0CLXwv6yWLvxHgNGiJ1Z3VGrUnW16K9EGyoNMYARPiJqSMaG
Grw26SUBzA485zzZfiIgnruriuiBQPp9dL5vvGAvRFODCcj45Jqpo25hTSADQTw3
kUUQ5WRRy2Din1VAEWJflCUMAf+VowODoglZP5YOSkf8lsBlVpekroWNFVaQehs3
MwIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----

Why? And what is the difference between the two PublicKey? Is the first PublicKey wrong?

Check the keys in an ASN.1 parser, e.g. https://lapo.it/asn1js/. The 1st key is inconsistent: the body corresponds to an RSA key in PKCS#1 format, while the header and footer belong to a PEM encoded key in X.509/SPKI format. The 2nd key is OK, a PEM encoded RSA key in X.509/SPKI format (for both the body as well as header and footer).

Thank Topaco, you are right, thank you very much
